# How to add elements of numpy array and make new numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an existing numpy array like this:

```
boxes = np.array([
        (59, 119, 175, 14),
        (147, 107, 66, 11)])
```

I'd like to make a new numpy array from the above numpy array such that:

```
element 2 = element 0 + element 2
element 3 = element 1 + element 3
```

i.e.

```
(59, 119, 234, 133),
(147, 108, 213, 119)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific problem, you can make a new numpy array where the first two columns remains the same and the columns 2 and 3 (0-based indexing) are the result of the sum between them and the columns 0 and 1, respectively, using [`column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html), which allows to stack arrays as columns.

Specifically, the code with your example would look like:

```
boxes = np.array([(59, 119, 175, 14), (147, 107, 66, 11)])
np.column_stack([boxes[:,0], boxes[:,1], boxes[:,2]+boxes[:,0], boxes[:,3]+boxes[:,1]])
```

and the output is

```
array([[ 59, 119, 234, 133], [147, 107, 213, 118]])
```

If you have a more general update rule, possibly this code can be generalized and thus the matrix can be iteratively built, column by column, using [`concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am expected to attach some explanations to my code but I don't really know what to explain. You really should read the numpy docs.

```
res = boxes.copy()
res[:, 2] += res[:, 0]
res[:, 3] += res[:, 1]
res

array([[ 59, 119, 234, 133],
       [147, 107, 213, 118]])
```

Comment: My code will update columns 2 and 3 as specified regardless of the array size as long as it has at least 4 columns.

Comment: If you mean column_n = column_n + column_(n-2) for n > 2 you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is no better than the other answers, for what it's worth..

```
import numpy as np

boxes = np.array([
        (59, 119, 175, 14),
        (147, 107, 66, 11)])

new_boxes = np.hstack([
  boxes[:,0].reshape((2,1)),
  boxes[:,1].reshape((2,1)),
  (boxes[:,0]+boxes[:,2]).reshape((2,1)),
  (boxes[:,1]+boxes[:,3]).reshape((2,1))])
```

resulting in:

```
array([[ 59, 119, 234, 133],
       [147, 107, 213, 118]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with one addition expression (one that handles a whole 2x2 block at a time).

```
In [137]: boxes = np.array([
        (59, 119, 175, 14),
        (147, 107, 66, 11)])
In [138]: res = boxes.copy()
In [139]: res[:,2:] += res[:,:2]
In [140]: res
Out[140]: 
array([[ 59, 119, 234, 133],
       [147, 107, 213, 118]])
```

You could skip it the copy if you don't mind modifying `boxes` itself.

The summation can also be calculate with a reshape and sum:

```
In [142]: boxes.reshape(2,2,2).sum(axis=1)
Out[142]: 
array([[234, 133],
       [213, 118]])
```

which leads me to another solution, using `cumsum`:

```
In [143]: np.cumsum(boxes.reshape(2,2,2),axis=1)
Out[143]: 
array([[[ 59, 119],
        [234, 133]],

       [[147, 107],
        [213, 118]]], dtype=int32)
In [144]: np.cumsum(boxes.reshape(2,2,2),axis=1).reshape(2,4)
Out[144]: 
array([[ 59, 119, 234, 133],
       [147, 107, 213, 118]], dtype=int32)
```

Slices and reshape are two handy ways of working with blocks of an array.